# How Can I pass two paths with spaces as arguments for a bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I have a bat file like:

> replace.exe Path1 Path2

Where Path1 and Path2 are folders paths with spaces like C:\Folder 1\ and C:\Folder 2\
So, the bat file look like:

> replace.exe C:\Folder 1\ C:\Folder 2\

of course, because of the space in the both paths the argument are passes improperly.

How can I do this?

Update:

I try replace.exe %1 %2 in the bat file and pass the arguments in the cmd like:

> Call replace.exe "C:\Folder 1\" "C:\Folder 2\"

this actually work. But I want to write the paths in bat file, not in the cmd windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
@echo off
set replace="C:\Folder 1\"
set with="C:\Folder 2\"
replace.exe %replace% %with%
```

work?

Comment: Don't worry, thank you, but it did't work. Details in kebs answer.

Comment: Have you tried setting the paths as variables in the batch file and then referencing the variables in your actual execution?

Comment: You mean like replace.exe %1 %2 ?

Comment: I edited my answer with a new idea... I have to admit, it's been a long while since I've done anything Windows, I'm mostly Linux :)

Comment: In Windows batch files, you typically put `@echo off` once at the beginning of the script, then other commands follow (they do not need to be prefixed with a `@` if they follow `echo off`). (I've edited your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

This should work: ;-)

```
replace.exe "C:\Folder 1\" "C:\Folder 2\"
```

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't work. I try  replace.exe %1 %2  in the bat file and pass the arguments in the cmd like: Call replace.exe "C:\Folder 1\" "C:\Folder 2\" and this actually work. But I want to write the paths in bat file, not in the cmd windows.